# Send rest request with Perl

Tags: linux, perl, shell

Is it possible to send rest request, including header authentication in perl/shell script/command line. And get the response?

Comment: Nitpick here. You don't send "rest requests". You send HTTP requests.

Comment: Nice tutorial here if you don't mind using some CPAN libraries https://developer.atlassian.com/server/fisheye-crucible/writing-a-rest-client-in-perl/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this if you want to manipulate the result in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $result=$ua->get("http://www.google.com/");

print $result->content;
```

Or, with basic HTTP authentication something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua=LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->credentials("www.pagetutor.com:80","My Secret Area","jimmy","page");

my $result=$ua->get("http://www.pagetutor.com/keeper/mystash/secretstuff.html");

print $result->content;
```

See http://www.pagetutor.com/keeper/http_authentication/index.html for where the password came from. Just the first random page I found which requires basic authentication.

Comment: This code doesn't show it but yes, you can set request headers and content too.  See the perldoc: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm

Comment: this works excellent +1, I've used default_header instead of credentials, I'm really new with perl. Can you show me or direct me to the right resource on this: how can I check if response is xml, and if response code is 200? thank you

Comment: You want to read the LWP documentation: http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm and look specifically at the response class: http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.02/lib/HTTP/Response.pm